# How to design this circuit in a simulator? What is wrong? (PSpice)

Tags: voltage, simulation, output, pspice, graph

I am trying to implement this circuit in the PSpice simulator:

[image]

I did it like this:

[image]

I am getting this result:

[image]

I was expecting something different than 0 in the output voltage. Could someone explain what is wrong?

Comment: which probe is the red line?

Comment: Your output signal willl be at the top of R6, and should be 0.2 V Peak-to-peak.

Comment: What sort of signal do you see across R4? This may tell you something about C2 & R6 which forms a high-pass filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Vin = 1 volt, the voltage at the output of the op-amp should also be 1 volt.

R4 and R5 form a 10:1 voltage divider so the voltage between them should be 0.1 volt.  However, your 100 ohm load resistor, R6, is effectively in parallel with R4, so the voltage divider is effectively 9K/100, rather than 9K/1000, so the voltage across R6 will be a bit under 0.01 volt, which will be barely visible in the pspice graph.

**EDIT**
Playing with this in LTSpice, I found that that program considers "10m" to be 10 milliohms - you need "10Meg" to get 10 megohms. The 10 milliohms will certainly act as a short, and leave very little signal at the op-amp input.

Comment: Just a minor remark: historically, SPICE has no notion of character case; `M` or `m` means the same thing: `milli`. This is why mishaps such as values for a capacitor written as `1F` will not be understood to mean 1 Farad, rather 1 `femto`.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen As I recall, we had to use all 3 letters "MEG" instead of just a capital M in the bad old days.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Yes, that's why I said that `M` or `m` both mean the same thing, and it's not `Mega`. That's why this answer is selected. Maybe I should have said "case insensitive" instead of "no notion of character case".

Answer (score 3):

R4 reduces the input to 10% @ 1k//9k
C2 is ~ 10K @ 10 Hz so R6 reduces that another 1% or on the order of 0.001 Vin

Answer (score 3):

As I'm sure was your intention, R4 and R5 form a potential divider, which will divide the opamp's output voltage by 10. Then, you further attenuate that signal with another divider, formed by C2 and R6. As a "back-of-the-envelope" calculation, we have a *very rough* idea of the effective impedance of C2 at the frequency of 10Hz that you are using here:

$$ Z_{C2} = \frac{1}{2\pi fC_2} = \frac{1}{2 \pi \cdot 10Hz \cdot 2 \mu F} \approx 10^4 \Omega$$

<sub>**Note:** please understand that this calculation is very approximate, and doesn't account for phase. It does, however, give us a ball-park idea of its influence in your circuit.</sub>

You can hopefully appreciate that the signal at the junction of C2 & R6 could be as small as \$ \frac{100}{10000} = \frac{1}{100} \$ of its source, which is already only \$ \frac{1}{10} \$ of the opamp's output! That's a combined attenuation of \$ \frac{1}{1000} \$, so it's no surprise you don't see anything in your trace.

Also, I notice that you used an [LM324](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snosc16d/snosc16d.pdf) opamp, which will draw about 50nA of current into its inputs (see "[input bias current](https://www.circuitbread.com/glossary/input-bias-current)"). If the purpose of R1 and R3 is to weakly hold the opamp input at half-way between the supplies (2.5V), then those values of 10MΩ are far too large. They really need to be low enough so that the 50nA of input current is insignificant compared to the current through the divider itself.

R1 and R3 together pass \$ \frac{5V}{R1 + R3} = \frac{5V}{10M\Omega + 10M\Omega} =250nA \$. The 50nA of input current is too "heavy" a chunk out of the 250nA, and it will consequently cause your "half-way" voltage to deviate significantly from the 2.5V you intended. A more sensible value for R1 and R3 would be 1MΩ, or even 100kΩ.

If you absolutely must use such high values (which is almost never recommended - see "[johnson noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise)"), then you'll need opamps with a suitably small input current, such as the [TL074](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl071h.pdf?ts=1629685037583&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F).

Answer (score 2):

Your circuit is AC-coupled with series capacitors, each on the order of microfarads. This essentially blocks DC and low-frequency signals below various cutoff frequencies which are higher than 10 Hz (the input frequency). The input frequency should be increased to reflect the kinds of frequencies this circuit is intended to handle.

According to a quick AC simulation of just the output filtering network, frequencies under 1k are certainly attenuated.